# Are PIE *suHnús "son" and *snusós "daughter-in-law" related?

Tags: etymology, proto-indo-european

One of the Proto-Indo-European words for "son" appears to have been *suHnús (Skt. *sūnú-*, Goth. *sunus*, etc.). The word for "daughter-in-law" is reconstructed as *snusós (Lat. *nurus*, Gk. νυός, etc.). Could the latter be derived from the former?

Semantically, deriving "daughter-in-law" from "son" seems plausible enough. Formally, the two words are similar enough to make such a derivation tempting, but I don't see any straightforward way that it would work. Has anyone suggested such a derivation?

Comment: To the close-voter(s): I really don't see how this is a language-specific grammar and usage question. It's a question about Proto-Indo-European reconstructions, which surely are a matter of (historical/comparative) linguistics?

Comment: What exactly is the question? is it "are they?", is it "has anyone?", or is it "is there any evidence?".

Comment: @user6726 Any or all of those, though I doubt the first is answerable.

Comment: @Draconis this site is really plagued by inappropriate and gratuitous use of that particular closing reason.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Re: "Has anyone suggested such a derivation"

Yes. Just a brief comment so far.

Looking at the relevant entries in NIL ([Nomina im indogermanischen Lexicon](https://www.winter-verlag.de/de/detail/978-3-8253-5359-9/Wodtko_ua_Hg_Nomina_im_Indogerm_Lexikon/)), I can see they mention such a possible connection (etymology 2 out of 4 mentioned there), citing [Kretschmer 1909](http://jstor.org/stable/40264557) (p. 36, ft. 1) and [Szemerényi 1977](http://dlib.nyu.edu/ancientworld/books/brill_awdl000004/1) (68ff).

The relevant passage from Kretschmer 1909:

[image]

As you can see, he mentions [Pedersen 1893](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Beitr%C3%A4ge_zur_Kunde_der_indogermanischen/MDJ1jBW7C2QC?hl=en&gbpv=1) (ff. 297), who  - in his turn - disagrees with [Bartholomae 1890](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Studien_zur_indogermanischen_Sprachgesch/KvsvAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=RA1-PA31&printsec=frontcover) (v.2, p. 31, footnote 5), because Bartholomae 1890 wrote that "wie man *snusā auf *sunu-sā zurückfüren kann, verstehe ich nicht", mentioning in his turn J. Schmidt etc. etc. cf. Pedersen "die alte Etymologie"

The relevant passage from Szemerényi 1977:

[image]

[image]

Bartholomae, Christian. 1890. Studien zur indogermanischen Sprachgeschichte. Halle: Max Niemeyer.

Kretschmer, Paul. "Zur Geschichte Der Griechischen Dialekte." Glotta 1, no. 1 (1909): 9-59.

Pedersen, Holger. 1893. Die idg. Form des Wortes für “Schwiegertochter”. Beiträger zur Kunde der indogermanischen Sprachen, 18, 293-298.

Szemerényi 1977. Studies in the kinship terminology ... in Acta Iranica 16 (pp. 1-240), also available online dlib.nyu.edu/ancientworld/books/brill_awdl000004/1